# Wort für irreführende Ironie?

Tags: single-word-request

Beispiel: Eine Person behauptet, sie würde jemanden vermissen, meint es aber nicht ernst und behauptet dies nur "aus Spaß" und freut sich darüber, dass die angesprochene andere Person dies für eine wahre Behauptung gehalten hat.

Mir sind bis jetzt nur schnippisch und mokant eingefallen, beides trifft es aber nicht.

Comment: Und wenn es kein Wort dafür gibt? Kennst Du eine Sprache, in der das mit einem Wort ausdrückbar ist?

Comment: Nein, ist mir nicht bekannt. Aber im Deutschen gibt es für viele feingliedrigen Sinndifferenzierungen ein eigenes Wort, vielleicht auch in diesem Fall.

Comment: Ist nicht "Ironie" selbst das gesuchte Wort? Wiktionary definiert das z. B. als "verhüllter Spott, bei dem ein Unterschied zwischen wörtlicher und wirklicher Bedeutung besteht" - das enthält doch eigentlich alles Beschriebene?

Comment: @IQV: Ironie zielt aber schon darauf ab, als solche erkannt zu werden, weswegen davon abgeraten wird, sie gegenüber kleinen Kindern zu verwenden. Hier soll es darum gehen, dass die Ironie nicht erkannt wird _und_ sich der Verwender über die Fehlinterpretation amüsiert, um Ironiemissdeutungsamüsement.

Comment: Klingt für mich ziemlich hinterfotzig.

Comment: Ich denke, "Ironie" ist hier im Titel fehl am Platz, da - wie schon ausgeführt - Ironie nur Ironie ist, falls der Empfänger sie erkennt. Das Beispiel und der Text sind ohne dem, was Ironie braucht.

Comment: Nein, Ironie ist unabhängig davon, ob der Empfänger sie erkennt. Das führt gerne mal zu Missverständnissen, aber es ändert nichts daran, dass der Sprecher die Nachtricht ironisch gemeint hat. Oben meint er sie definitiv aber nicht ironisch.

Comment: @infinitezero: finde ich schon: der Sender muss zu erkennen geben, dass es ironisch gemeint war, doch ob es erkannt wird, hängt vom Empfänger ab. Solange der das nicht erkennt... "was jedoch zu erkennen gegeben wird" (https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ironie), "Die erfolgreiche Verwendung von Ironie zeugt nicht nur von der erfolgreichen Reflexion des eigenen Wissens, sondern auch vom erfolgreichen Erkennen des Wissens des Gegenübers " (https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironie)

Comment: @Entgleisungsvorgang: bitte Frage eindeutig gestalten, ob es um Ironie (=Täuschung wird erkannt & auch explizit zum Erkennen angedeutet) oder Täuschung (=Täuschung wird eigentlich nicht erkannt)

Comment: @ShegitBrahm du sagst es doch selbst "Die erfolgreiche Verwendung [...]". Und ob es "erkannt wird, hängt vom Empfänger ab". Ich kann Dinge trotzdem ironisch sagen, ob mein Gegenüber das jetzt erkennt oder nicht. Es ist also **unabhängig** davon.

Comment: @infinitezero: und was ist mit dem Rest des Zitats "sondern auch vom erfolgreichen Erkennen des Wissens des Gegenübers"? Erst dann ist gesendete Ironie auch empfangende Ironie, somit erst dann vollständig kommuniziert. Sich darauf zu berufen "das habe ich so gemeint" geht nicht, wenn verlangt ist, zu wissen, wie der Gegenüber es verstehen müsste. Oder wie nennst Du es, wenn Deine ironische Bemerkung ernst genommen wird? War das dann Ironie, obwohl Du erklären musstest, dass es Ironie war? Wie steht es in dem Fall um die Rezeption des Gegenübers?

Comment: Ich sehe schon, du verstehst genau, was ich meine :-)

Comment: Ironie ist für mich auch Ironie wen sie nicht ankommt. Manchmal ist das ja auch der gewünschte Effekt, z.B. wenn man jemanden beleidigen möchte ohne das er es merkt. Das beleidigt ja gleich doppelt weil man den gegenüber für so dumm hält das er nicht mal die Ironie/die Beleidigung erkennt. Oder gibt es dafür ein passenderes Wort?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Die Antwort ist vielleicht offensichtlicher, als du es dir vorstellst.

Was du beschreibst, ist eine

> bewusst falsche, auf Täuschung angelegte Aussage

Das ist [laut Duden](https://www.duden.de/node/91304/revision/91340) die Definition für eine **Lüge**.

Comment: Das passt nicht, weil es gar nicht die Absicht ist, den Anderen irrezuführen, sondern nur eine Reaktion auf dessen unerwartetes Nichtverstehen einer Ironie.

Comment: Ich finde die Antwort ziemlich gut. Der in der Frage geschriebene Satz zeigt eine deutliche Intention, eine inkorrekte Information zu vermitteln. Auch lügen genannt.

Comment: Das ist falsch. Ironie ist versteckter Spott, aber er ist nur oberflächlich versteckt und die Ironie zielt darauf, erkannt zu werden.

Comment: Ironie ist nicht böswillig. Lüge passt sehr gut in meinen Augen.

Answer (score 5):

Unwahres erzählen und sich freuen, wenn es geglaubt wird?

Umgangssprachlich nennt man das

> Verarschung

und in gehobener Sprache

> jemandem einen Bären aufbinden

Soeben noch gefunden:

> [foppen](https://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/foppen)

Das trifft es wohl am besten.

Comment: Foppen finde ich zu harmlos.

Comment: @infinitezero: Wenn der/die Gefoppte geradezu geschockt ist von der falschen Nachricht, könnte man es _»erschrecken«_ nennen.

Comment: Passt nicht, weil es gar nicht die Absicht ist, den Anderen irrezuführen, sondern nur eine Reaktion auf dessen unerwartetes Nichtverstehen einer Ironie.

Comment: @userunknown: Aus der Frage lese ich durchaus bewusste Irreführung heraus.

Comment: Große Geister lesen aus beliebigen Texten alles mögliche heraus, das ist wohl wahr. "Eine Person behauptet, sie würde jemanden vermissen, meint es aber nicht ernst und behauptet dies nur <aus Spaß>"

Answer (score 2):

Wie schon [Pollitzer ausgeführt](https://german.stackexchange.com/a/52589/36160) hat, ist es salopp gesagt `verarschen`. In jedem Fall muss der Gegenüber & sein "Wissen" bekannt sein, sonst gelingt keine Täuschung.

Außerdem ist die Auflösung der Wahrheit kurze Zeit nach der Täuschung zu erwarten, sonst könnte der Täuschende (zu) lange darauf warten, dass es dem Getäuschten auffällt.

Da der Titel mit "Ironie" keineswegs zum Beispiel passt [[Ironie](https://de.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ironie)= das Erkennen der Täuschung wird erwartet vs. Beispiel:das Missverstehen wird erwartet] , gehe ich nur auf den Text ein.

[Davon ausgehend andere Begriffe](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Verarschung), die auf das Beispiel passen und jeweils eine leicht andere Bedeutung haben [können]:

- [Bluff](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Bluff): eine (eigentlich) simple Täuschung, meist in einem Spiel, auch in größerem Maßstab verwendet (z.B. Kriegstaktik), hier steht das Tun im Vordergrund, nicht das Reden, außerdem ist der "gebluffte" danach im Nachteil
- [List](https://www.dwds.de/wb/List): einigermaßen komplexer Handlungsstrang, mit dem ein Ziel erreicht wird. Der Fokus liegt darauf, dass der "Überlistende" mit Intelligenz ein scheinbar unmöglich erreichbares Ziel erreicht - der Nachteil des "Überlisteten" ist kein direktes Ziel
- [Finte](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Finte): bisschen ähnlich wie Bluff & List: Gegenüber wird dazu verleitet, etwas zu tun, das er gar nicht wollte, der "Fintenleger" dadurch sein Ziel erreicht
- [Trickserei](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Trickserei): "Kombination" aus Bluff und Finte, d.h., etwas vortäuschen, den Gegenüber zu einer für ihn ungünstigen Handlung verleiten und damit das eigene Ziel erreichen, der Fokus liegt somit auf dem Tun
- [Veräppelung](https://www.dwds.de/wb/Ver%C3%A4ppelung): Der Fokus liegt auf dem Reden und dem Witz, nachdem die Täuschung recht bald geklärt wurde - zumindest ist ein gewisser Erwartungswert, dass die Täuschung recht bald durchschaut wird

Comment: Teile der Frage zu ignorieren, weil sie nicht zur Antwort passen, ist generell keine gute Idee. Es ist nicht Absicht, den Anderen irrezuführen, sondern nur das Amüsement über ein unerwartetes Nichtverstehen einer Ironie.

Comment: @userunknown: grundsätzlich vertrete ich auch die Meinung. Ich werde das daher umformulieren, dass die Frage für mich nicht völlig klar ist, d.h., ob Ironie eine Rolle spielt oder nicht. @"unerwartetes Nichtverstehen" - genau das geht für mich nicht aus dem Beispiel der Frage hervor, sondern es wird erwartet, dass es (erstmal) falsch verstanden wird.

Comment: Ironie ist zwar versteckter Spott, aber nur so weit versteckt, dass der andere kurz zögert. Sie zielt darauf erkannt zu werden, gelingt aber nicht immer (Beispiel: Internet). Daraus kann eine eigene Komik erwachsen. Es ist etwas gänzlich anderes als Finte, List, Veräpplung oder Verarsche. Unklarheiten sollte man vorab über die Kommentarfunktion klären.

Comment: @userunknown: danke, dann haben wir das gleiche Verständnis von Ironie. Und ich kann diese Definition _nicht_ auf das gestellte Beispiel anwenden. Der Spaß entsteht dort, weil der Empfänger es für bare Münze nimmt. Somit beißt es sich mit dem Titel.

Comment: Schade, ich habe mein Bestes versucht, zu erklären, wie eine Ironie fehlgedeutet werden und dies beim Verwender zu Belustigung führen kann. Insbesondere in größeren Gruppen, wenn gleich mehrere die Ironie nicht bemerken, andererseits diese aber auch mehreren anderen nicht verborgen bleibt, kann das sehr komisch sein.